# Get a vector of map keys without copying?

Tags: c++, optimization, copy, clone, shared-ptr

I have a map of objects where keys are `std::string`. How can I generate a vector of keys without copying the data?

Do I need to change my map to use `std::shared_ptr<std::string>` as keys instead? Or would you recommend something else?

My current code goes like this:

`MyClass.h`

```cpp
class MyClass {
private:
    std::map <std::string, MyType> my_map;
public:
    const std::vector<std::string> MyClass::getKeys() const;
}
```

`MyClass.cpp`

```cpp
const std::vector<std::string> MyClass::getKeys() const
{
    std::vector<std::string> keys = std::vector<std::string>();
    for (const auto& entry : my_map)
        keys.push_back(entry.first); // Data is copied here. How can I avoid it?
    return keys;
}
```

Comment: Looks like unnecessary optimization.

Comment: You need to think about lifetimes and ownership. If I call `getKeys()` and then remove an element from the map, what should happen?

Comment: C++20 has [std::views::keys](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/keys_view), to give you a read-only view of the keys of a range, i.e. `std::views::keys(my_map)` will let you iterate and do other range operations on the keys of the map, without copying the elements.

Comment: I would second @Kevin and ask: do you need a _vector_ or just the ability to iterate over keys?

Comment: Good point, I don't need a `vector` per se. I will look into the view thing that I didn't know about. Thank you.

And you are right about lifetimes. I probably have an issue there. Would a view help with that?

Comment: Applying `const` to a return type when the return type is an object is pointless. If the map isn't modified after the `getKeys()` call returning one of the following may actually do the trick: `std::vector<std::string_view>`, `std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<std::string const>>`, `std::vector<std::string const*>`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Kevin, std::views::keys was pretty much made for this. The view it produces is a lightweight object, not much more than a pointer to the range argument, which solves the ownership and lifetime issues. Iterating over this view is identical to iterating over the map, the only difference is that the view's iterator dereferences to the first element of the underlying map value.

As for some code, it is pretty simple:

```
// ...
#include <ranges>

class MyClass {
private:
    std::map<std::string, MyType> my_map;
public:
    std::ranges::view auto getKeys() const;
};

std::ranges::view auto MyClass::getKeys() const
{
    return std::views::keys(my_map);
}
```

Since ranges and concepts go hand in hand, I've used the `std::ranges::view` to constrain the `auto` return type. This is a useful way to let the compiler and user of your function know that it will return a particular category of object, without having to specify a potentially complicated type.